# Search in Facebook group through query parameter

Tags: facebook, search

I have a question about FB group search through URL. I want to search a FB group contents by sending a query parameter like this https://www.facebook.com/groups/905344972984695/search/?q=tasty%20foods
But when I open this in new window, it opens the main group or if I am not logged in then it shows an error without any details.
So how can I achieve this search without using FB graph or authentication?

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape you have to use the API.

Comment: I don't want to scrap any data, just want to redirect user to Facebook page with selected results based on the query parameter passed as search.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this through graph API, where user will be sent to Facebook page, I don't want to show filtered result in my website, I want users to go to Facebook and see the results there.